# omitting the for loops in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I am going to compute the following equation in which there are four different variables. Is there any possible way to omit the for loops for computing this equation?

```
 Z = p1 * sqrt(q1^2 + q2^2 * p2^2)
```

in which the variables are:

```
p=[(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4)
   (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)
   (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4)
   (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4)];
```

in which the first number is p1 and the second will be p2(e.g. in (1,2), p1=1, p2=2).
and:

```
q=[(5,5) (5,6) (5,7) (5,8)
   (6,5) (6,6) (6,7) (6,8)
   (7,5) (7,6) (7,7) (7,8)
   (8,5) (8,6) (8,7) (8,8)]
```

again the first number will be q1 and second one will be q2.

How can i comput Z for each of them without for loop?

Comment: I don't see any for loop. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @Daniel I didn't write the for loops here, I want to compute the Z for each p1, p2, q1 and q2. Actually for each combination of these four variables i will have a Z.

Comment: @user3482383 Check out a new solution based on `bsxfun` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25949712/3293881) that shows some promise with runtime performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute **for each combination of the four variables** without `for` loops, use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
[pp1 pp2 qq1 qq2] = ndgrid(p1,p2,q1,q2);
Z = pp1 .* sqrt(qq1.^2 + qq2.^2 + pp2.^2);
```

For your example, this produces a result `Z` of size 16 x 16 x 16 x 16. First index of `Z` refers to `p1`, second to `p2`, third to `q1` and fourth to `q2`.

BTW, in your code you would need to replace `length` to `numel`; as it stands you are not taking all elements from each matrix.

---

*After question edit:*
To compute **for each combination of `p1` and `q1`**, with the index of `p2` being the same as that of `p1` and the index of `q2` being the same as that of `q1`:

```
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(p1), 1:numel(q1));
Z = pp1(ii) .* sqrt(qq1(jj).^2 + qq2(jj).^2 + pp2(ii).^2);
```

which gives `Z` of size 16 x 16 in your case.

Comment: How about the edit i have done? How can i change your idea for this situation?

Comment: I tried using ndgrid instead of for loops, but the time of calculation is more the one in which for loops are used!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your nested loops look like this -

```
Z = zeros(length(p1),length(p2),length(q1),length(q2));
for i=1:length(p1)
    for j=1:length(p2)
        for m = 1:length(q1)
            for n = 1:length(q2)
                Z(i,j,m,n) = p1(i) * sqrt(q1(m)^2 + q2(n)^2 * p2(j)^2);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Note: `numel` or `size` would be a better parameter to use than `length`, but keeping `length` here as used in your codes, before you did revisions with your question.

Now, in `p1`, `q1`, `p2` and `q2` you have grid data and thus many identical values, which can be used for code optimization and thus vectorization. Here's a vectorized solution with `bsxfun` -

```
impvals = bsxfun(@times,p1(:,1)',sqrt(q1(:,1).^2+(p2(1)*q2(1))^2)); %//'
Z = repmat(permute(impvals,[2 3 1 4]),[1 4 1 4]);
```

I ran this with your given `4x4` data for each of those four 2D arrays for `100000` times (for a better runtime measurement) and this were the runtimes -

```
Elapsed time (with for-loops) is 5.684010 seconds.
Elapsed time (with bsxfun) is 4.441675 seconds.
```

Comment: In your opinion, if these nested loops be written in C++, what would be the time?

Comment: @user3482383 What would be the runtime? I think computer must be the better guy to answer that. Why not write a C++ program and test it out on your computer?

Comment: I am not familiar with C++, so i asked your experience with `for loop`s in different programming languages

Comment: @user3482383 I don't have much either. Also, that has to be a separate question as this was MATLAB specific.